# SQL Server convert date to String MMMYYDD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Im trying to convert date value into this `MMMYYDD` String format, using native Sql server 2008 r2 function,

I checked here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

and still I can't find matching format.

any ideas?

Comment: could you check your question you write times M in your format is this correct ?

Comment: @Gorock yes its correct, i want MMMYYDD so today date will be MAR1521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
select convert(varchar(3), @date, 7) + convert(varchar(4), @date, 12)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/1410)</kbd>**